# BLToolKit: how to insert a list of objects?

Tags: sql, batch-insert, bltoolkit

Is it possible with BLToolKit (http://bltoolkit.net) to create a set of records for list of object (batch insert)?

If yes, how is this possible?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
using (var db = new DbManager())
    db.InsertBatch(list);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
using (var db = new DbManager())
{
    var ret = (from s in db.tablename
               select new ObjectList
               {
                   Id = (int)s.Id,
                   Name = s.Name
               }).ToList();
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var db = new DbManager())
{
    db.SetSpCommand("Person_Insert")
      .ExecuteForEach<Person>(list);
}
```

Where `list` is provided by other means of your application functionality.